# How to mock interface implementation

Tags: go, testing, mocking

myinterface.go

```golang
type MyInterface interface {
    fun1() string
    fun2() int
    fun3() bool
}


func Foo(mi MyInterface) string {
    return mi.fun1()
}
```

myinterface_test.go

```golang
type MyInterfaceImplementation struct{}

func (mi MyInterfaceImplementation) fun1() string {
    return "foobar"
}

func (mi MyInterfaceImplementation) fun2() int {
    return int(100)
}

func (mi MyInterfaceImplementation) fun3() bool {
    return false
}


func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    mi := MyInterfaceImplementation{}
    val := Foo(mi)
    if val != "foobar" {
        t.Errorf("Expected 'foobar', Got %s", mi.fun1())
    }
}
```

While writing tests for `Foo`, is it necessary to do a mock implementation of the interface `MyInterface` (as it requires us to implement `fun2` and `fun3` as well which are not being used in `Foo`)?

Is there any way in which we can write tests for `Foo` wherein we just need to write the mock implementation of `fun1` and not for `fun2` and `fun3`?

Also, what's the ideal way to test such use of interfaces in Go?

Comment: You can omit the mock implementation of methods you don't need by embedding the interface into the mock. Just keep in mind that if anything in the code under test calls the unimplemented methods it will cause `panic`. https://play.golang.org/p/wSjz5SoEHyv

Comment: What do you want to test? `Foo`? Then you don't need to mock anything, you just need to pass a value that implements `MyInterface`. If you already have an implementation like `MyInterfaceImplementation`, simply use that.

Comment: Also note that if `Foo()` only uses the `func1()` method, then it shouldn't expect a value that implements `MyInterface`, only an interface with the single `func1()` method, or even better: it should just expect a function value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement all the methods. Interface is a contract and you need to fulfill this contract.

If you're sure that `fun2` and `fun3` methods will not be called, then it usually means that your interface contract is too wide. Consider extracting `fun1` into dedicated interface in such case.